# Trying to access a global variables method in javascript, but only works certain times

Tags: javascript, variables, dom, global

I have three files: tasker_matic.js, tasker.js, and tasker.html. I am not allowed to edit tasker.html or tasker.js AT ALL. I am to use tasker_matic to communicate with the tasker.js library.

Right now I am trying to access its login function. When the login is correct, it should pop up with an alert saying it worked, and when it isn't correct, it should pop up with an alert saying forbidden. This is where I am having the problem. If I continually click on the login button, it will eventually pop up with an alert, but not every time. Does anyone know why this is?

Tasker_matic.js:

```
function login(e) {
    var userName = document.getElementById("usernameInput").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("passwordInput").value;
    tasker.login( userName, password, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            alert( err );
        }
        else if (user) {
            alert("it worked");
        }
    });
}

 function createTask(s) {
     let descNode;
     let theTable = document.getElementById('tasks');
     let row = document.createElement('tr');
     let description = document.createElement('th');
     descNode = document.createTextNode(s);
     description.append(descNode);
     row.append(description);
     theTable.append(row);

 }
```

tasker.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Tasker</title>
    <script src="tasker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tasker_matic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="tasker_matic.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div id="login" class="on">
      <h1>Login</h1><br>
        <form style="width:50%">
          <input id="usernameInput" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control">
          <input id="passwordInput" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
          <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="login(event)">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="home" class="off">
      <h1>Tasker <small><span class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="logout" onclick="logout()"></span></small></h1>
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="descField">Description</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Description" id="descField">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cField">Color Code</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="color" id="cField"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dField">Due Date</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" id="dField"/>
          </div>

          <input class="form-control" type="button" value="+" id="addButton" onclick="addTask()"/>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="well well-sm">
        <form class="form-inline">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="search" id="searchField" style="width:25%" onkeyup="searchTextChange()"/>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" id="incompleteBox" onclick="incompleteChange()"/>Incomplete Only
            </label>

          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" id="overdueBox" onclick="overdueChange()"/>Over-due only
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <table id="tasks" class="table table-striped">
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

tasker.js:

```
let tasker = (function () {
    let verbs = [
        "make",
        "install",
        "update",
        "generate data for",
        "talk to",
        "schedule a time for",
        "develop a plan for",
        "knit",
        "create",
        "build",
        "write",
        "get",
        "finish",
        "call",
        "arrange",
        "submit",
        "talk to",
        "do",
        "protest",
        "collect",
        "shop for"
    ];

    let nouns = [
        "a cake",
        "the boat",
        "our wedding",
        "the garage",
        "the tow truck",
        "our shed",
        "1090 tax form",
        "the IRS agent",
        "milk",
        "some LED lights",
        "monthly budget",
        "marketing plan",
        "the flowers",
        "an albatross"
    ];

    let userNames = [
        "frodo baggins",
        "gandalf gray",
        "smaug dragon"
    ];

    let Task = function (id, ownerId, desc, due, color, complete) {
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.due = due;
        this.color = color;
        this.complete = complete;
        this.id = id || randomId();
    };

    let randomId = function () {
        return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
            var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
            return v.toString(16);
        });
    }

    let randomColor = function () {
        let pad = function (v) {
            return v.length == 1 ? '0' + v : v;
        }
        r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256).toString(16);
        g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256).toString(16);
        b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256).toString(16);
        return '#' + pad(r) + pad(g) + pad(b);
    }

    let randomDate = function () {
        year = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14 + 2010);
        month = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
        day = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31);
        return new Date(year, month, day);
    };

    let choose = function (things) {
        let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * things.length);
        return things[i];
    }

    let randomDescription = function () {
        return choose(verbs) + ' ' + choose(nouns);
    };

    let makeList = function (ownerId, n) {
        result = [];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
            result.push(new Task(null,
                ownerId,
                randomDescription(),
                randomDate(),
                randomColor(),
                choose([true, false])));
        }
        return result;
    }

    let updateTask = function( oldTask, editedTask ) {
        let propertiesToCopy = ['desc', 'due', 'color', 'complete' ];
        propertiesToCopy.forEach( prop => {
            if( editedTask.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
                oldTask[prop] = editedTask[prop];
            }
        });
    }

    let state = {
        users: userNames.reduce(function (acc, cv) {
            let parts = cv.split(' '); //
            let name = parts[0];
            let email = parts[0][0] + parts[1] + '@uwlaxer.edu';
            let id = randomId();
            let password = parts[1];
            let tasks = makeList(id, Math.random() * 50 + 20).reduce((acc, t) => { acc[t.id] = t; return acc; }, {});
            acc[id] = {
                name: name,
                email: email,
                id: id,
                password: password,
                tasks: tasks
            };
            return acc;
        }, {}),
        user: null
    };

    let getTask = function (ownerId, id) {
        try {
            return state.users[ownerId].tasks[id];
        } catch (e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    let getUserByName = function (name) {
        for (id in state.users) {
            if (state.users[id] && state.users[id].name === name) {
                return state.users[id];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    let taskList = function (ownerId) {
        let result = [];
        for (let tid in state.user.tasks) {
            result.push(state.user.tasks[tid]);
        }
        return result.sort((a, b) => b.due.getTime() - a.due.getTime());
    }

    let respond = function (error, value, cb) {
        window.setTimeout(() => cb(error, value), Math.random() * 1500);
    }

    let copyTask = function( task ) {
        return new Task(task.id, task.ownerId, task.desc, task.due, task.color, task.complete);
    }

    return {
        login: function ( username, passwd, cb) {
            let user = getUserByName( username );
            if (user && user.password === passwd) {
                state.user = user;
                let cleansedUser = { name: user.name, email: user.email, id: user.id };
                respond(null, cleansedUser, cb);
            } else {
                respond('forbidden', null, cb);
            }
        },

        logout: function (cb) {
            state.user = null;
            respond(null, true, cb);
        },

        tasks: function (ownerId, cb) {
            if (ownerId === state.user.id) {
                let tasks = taskList(ownerId).map(u => new Task(u.id, u.ownerId, u.desc, u.due, u.color, u.complete));
                respond(null, tasks, cb);
            } else {
                respond('forbidden', null, cb);
            }
        },

        add: function (ownerId, task, cb) {
            if (state.user.id == ownerId) {
                if (task.desc && task.due && task.color) {
                    let due = new Date(task.due);
                    let task = new Task(task.id, ownerId, task.desc, due, task.color, Boolean(task.complete));
                    state.users[ownerId].tasks[task.id] = task;
                    respond(null, task, cb);
                } else {
                    respond('invalid task', null, cb);
                }
            } else {
                respond('forbidden', null, cb);
            }
        },

        delete: function (ownerId, taskId, cb) {
            if (state.user.id === ownerId) {
                let task = state.users[ownerId].tasks[taskId];
                delete state.users[ownerId].tasks[taskId];

                if (task) {
                    respond(null, task, cb);
                } else {
                    respond('no such task', null, cb);
                }
            } else {
                respond('forbidden', null, cb);
            }
        },

        edit: function (ownerId, taskId, task, cb) {
            if (state.user.id == ownerId) {
                if (taskId) {
                    let oldTask = getTask(ownerId, taskId);
                    if( oldTask) {
                        updateTask( oldTask, task );                        
                        respond( null, copyTask( oldTask ), cb );
                    } else {
                        respond( 'no such task', null, cb );
                    }                    
                } else {
                    respond( 'no such task', null, cb );
                }
            } else {
                respond( 'forbidden', null, cb );
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

Comment: It looks like it will only alert if there's an error or a user. Are you sure an incorrect password always causes an error?

Comment: I think so. In the tasker.js file, for the login function, it will either respond with a null error message and user object if the user is valid and the user.password equals the entered password. Otherwise, it will respond with an error message and a null object. If I type in the correct name and password, smaug and dragon, for example, it won't always alert, but it eventually will.

Comment: I see it now. The login method should always deliver either err or user. Interesting that it doesn't sometimes.

Comment: Either it doesn't sometimes or, maybe it's actually doing something interesting that takes a while.

Comment: It wouldn't have anything to do with window.setTimeout(), would it? I have never used it before but from what I am reading, that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: oh LOL. Yeah, that is waiting some multiple of 1.5 seconds for every response. You need to wait a few seconds for your callback to be called.

Comment: Okay. I think I am getting on the right track. Still a little confused though. Even when I just press it once, I get no alert message.

Comment: Well, stick an `else` in your callback to see if somehow it's getting called with `err` and `user` both null. Other than that, it seems like you should always get an alert within 1.5 seconds.